# How whitespace (in data) is treated by XML Parser?

Tags: xml, w3c

If this is a sample XML::

```
<root>
  <tag1>data
    data
     data</tag1>
  <tag2>
  </tag2>
  <tag3> </tag3>
</root>
```

This file is viewed differently in different browsers and XML viewer/editors,

some viewers display 1st `<tag/>` element as `<tag>data data data</tag>` some display as is,

Some viewers, treat *new line* as *nbsp(space)* and some treat *space* and *new line* as null,

What is the standard approach for this white-space issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conclusion**

I validated the same XML against XSD which had defined `<tag1/> <tag2/> ...` with enumeration values, (copied same value of the tags) when I altered the contents of `<tag>` by adding/removing whitespace. The schema acknowledged **mismatch** which concludes that .. *in general XML parser **won't** ingore the whitespace* :)
But the transformation ignores whitespace, thats why the browsers ignore it too where as notepad is honest to display as is. ;)

Source/courtesy :: [Nic Gibson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88002/nic-gibson)'s comment on [jambox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212339/how-whitespace-in-data-is-treated-by-xml-parser/4214134#4214134)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space

I believe that means it is optional but default behaviour should be to ignore non-significant whitespace.

Can you give me an example of an implementation which is showing the line breaks?

Comment: hello there, thanks for responding, you want me to reveal example of **code or xml viewer**?

Comment: Usage of such data is in case of Source codes, which we need to send via XML.

Comment: and example of viewer which ignores white space is IE, opera, FF and other browsers, where as .NET xml parser doesn't ignore any whitespace and accept the newline/tab/space as is. (the mentioned link is useful so accepting ur answer as BA) regards. :)

Comment: That sounds as though you are seeing the difference between something being parsed and then rendered and something being parsed only. The browsers are rendering the XML (probably with XSLT).

Comment: @infant programmer - XML has pretty strict whitespace rules. Most browsers render XML as a tree. The likelihood is that browsers are internally converting the XML to (something like) HTML and then applying HTML whitespace rules to it. HTML (if I remember correctly) collapses whitespace.

Comment: @Nic, HTML, yes, collapses whitespace, if one wants to retain whitespace (in HTML code designing) has to use either `<pre/>` or `nbsp;`

Comment: Sorry yes I got that the wrong way around - should preserve whitespace by default.

Comment: @Jambox, your answer is still valid, but incase of browsers which implement the Tranformation :)